# SAS : Proc format The SAS task name is [FORMAT (] Segmentation Violation Issue

Tags: sas, format, proc

I am getting an issue while trying to create SAS format which have over 90m record :

```
proc format cntlin=fmtdata lib=temp_lib;
```

The error is -

```
MPRINT(CREATE_FORMAT):  run;
ERROR:  An exception has been encountered.
Please contact technical support and provide them with the following traceback information:
The SAS task name is [FORMAT (]
Segmentation Violation
```

Using work or permanent library is throwing this error.

Traceback of the Exception:

Can some one please provide view as using HASH might throw the same error?

Comment: What is the goal here? What kind of Format do you want to create?

Comment: any format to lookup values like say 1 - abc, 2 - xyz........90m - zyzyzyzyzy

Comment: And you want to do this with a hash object instead or?

Comment: I'm afraid hash object throw same error. Any workarounds using format?

Comment: Please show your entire code and log using hash objects.